# Mamba installing a package into wrong environment

Tags: docker, conda, mamba

The background is, I'm responsible for maintaining a fancy Docker image that is used by our team for analytics. It uses a [Jupyter notebook image](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/selecting.html) as the base, and then adds various customisations, extra packages, etc.

One of the team members recently wanted to run Tensorflow. No problem, I'll just run `mamba install` and add it to the image. However, this created an issue: Tensorflow 2.4.3 (the latest version) is somehow incompatible with R 4.1.1 (also the latest version) or something else in the ecosystem, causing R to to be downgraded to 3.6.3. So I created a new environment and installed TF into that:

```
FROM hongooi/jupytermodelrisk:1.0.0

RUN mamba create -n tensorflow --clone base

# Make RUN commands use the new environment
RUN echo "conda activate tensorflow" >> ~/.bashrc

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

RUN mamba install -y 'tensorflow=2.4.3'
```

But when I rebuilt the image, I found that while the tensorflow env had been created, the Tensorflow package had been installed into the base env, not the tensorflow env. Has anyone else encountered this? I can verify, if I login to the container, that the tensorflow env has been created: it just doesn't contain the Tensorflow package.

I don't get this problem if run the `create`, `activate` and `install` commands from inside the container. It's only when I try to do it in the Dockerfile.

I use mamba instead of conda because the latter takes forever to run, given the number of packages installed. In fact, trying to run `conda install tensorflow` crashes after ~5 hours.

Comment: Not an expert on dockerfiles, but you could just use the `-n` flag to the install command to specify the environment `mamba install -n tensorflow -y tensorflow=2.4.3`

Comment: Ah I think the issue could be that you are adding your command to the wrong startup file. Since you have `--login` for your bash, you need to modify `.bash_profile` instead. Could you try that?

Comment: @FlyingTeller using the `-n` flag worked! I'm not sure why, but if you post that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: This article on running conda envs in docker might be useful: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-conda-dockerfile/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an expert on dockerfiles, but in general you could just use the `-n` flag to the install command to specify the target environment for the installation like so:

```
mamba install -n tensorflow -y tensorflow=2.4.3
```